# How to use the results of a query as a field in another query than in another query - QUERY 'A' to QUERY 'B' then QUERY 'C'?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to know how to write a SQL query  - situation is I have a query 'A' which pulls multiple columns one of them is PERSON_ID from PATIENTS TABLE, using query 'A' results I want to write query 'B' which have 'ORDERS_ID' from ORDERS TABLE once I get the result of query 'B', then I want to use this query results to write query 'C' which will give me all the 'RESULTS_ID' from RESULTS TABLE. Please guide me how to achieve this. My database is Oracle.

Comment: Why can't you just use joins?

Comment: performance issue we have tons of data.

Comment: Joins are something that relational database (like Oracle) are extremely good at. So if you have a performance problem, can you provide some metrics such as table sizes, cardinalities (don't say "tons" because it is not helpful) and some debug, such as a SQL Monitor report.

Comment: Use result of query A in query B which in turn is used in query C sounds like nested subqueries - there's nothing special about that. One thing to be careful with is that a query can only be correlated to a query one level above it (not more). Or you can use the `with` clause to write the successive queries, which will make the code a lot easier to read. Beyond that you will have to give a much more concrete example of your data structure, what you are trying to do, and what issue you run into and you need help with. For now your question is "too broad".

Comment: In addition to what BobC wrote: what you are trying to do is to "join" the data _outside_ of the database. That is almost always slower then letting the database do what it was designed for.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a singe query which a combination of A, B and C, where this query is a JOIN between PATIENTS, ORDERS and RESULTS.
I have no idea of the structure of your table; and in future it would be useful if you could give examples, so I'm making a guess, but I think you want something like:

```
select blah, blah
from patients p
join order o
  on p.patient_id = o.order_id
join results r
  on o.order_id = r.order_id
```